# TypeError: Cannot set property of undefined

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

need some support.

I want to show data by click a button or link

```
<div v-for="hpTheme in hpThemes" :key="hpTheme.id">
      <button class="button round success" @click="showDetails(hpTheme.id)">{{hpTheme.hpTitle 
}}</button>
</div>


<script>
export default {
 data() {
  return {
   hpTheme: { hpTitle: '', hpContent: '' },

  hpThemes: [
    {
      id: 1,
      hpTitle: 'title',
      hpContent: 'content'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      hpTitle: 'title2',
      hpContent: 'content2'
    } 
   ]
 }
},
methods: {
showDetails(id) {

  for (var i = 0; i <= this.hpThemes.length; i++) {

    if (id === this.hpThemes[i].id) {
      this.theme.hpTitle = this.hpThemes[i].hpTitle
      this.theme.hpContent = this.hpThemes[i].hpContent
    }
   }
  }
}
</script>
```

But I get this error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'hpTitle' of undefined.
How to solve?
Thanks for support.

Comment: ! If my answer works for you and you are happy - then in general you would accept the answer. This will not only help other people with the same issue but it will also mean people are more likely to help you in the future with any other issues you have. You can read about accepting here: stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

variable `i` shouldn't equal to the `this.hpThemes.length`

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.hpThemes.length; i++) { // replace '<=' operator with '<'
   ...
}
```

Comment: good, `hpTheme` is not defined as property, please update your answer

Answer (score 2):

I have just changed the this.theme to this.hpTheme below. Hope this works for you.

```
showDetails(id) {
  for (var i = 0; i <= this.hpThemes.length; i++) {
    if (id === this.hpThemes[i].id) {
      this.hpTheme.hpTitle = this.hpThemes[i].hpTitle
      this.hpTheme.hpContent = this.hpThemes[i].hpContent
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: it should also be `i <= (this.hpThemes.length-1)` look to @William's answer

Answer (score 2):

@WilliamWang's answer is perfect to remove that error, but your code be more clean and shorter if you just pass the clicked theme as parameter then assign it to `this.theme` :

```
@click="showDetails(hpTheme)"
```

and

```
methods: {
  showDetails(theme) {
    this.hpTheme={hpTitle: theme.hpTitle, hpContent: theme.hpContent }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot so far Amaarshall and Boussadjra.. this is working perfectly..